# Stopping WordPress' WYSIWYG Editor from Converting "didn't" into "didn'''''''''t"?

Tags: plugins, errors, dashboard

**didn't becomes didn''''''''''''''''''t** in Wordpress WYSIWYG editor. I searched a lot in google then found this solution

- http://www.lancebledsoe.com/how-to-turn-off-wordpress-smart-quotes/

I followed the steps of this article but when I activated the plugin I got this error at the top of dashboard:

> The plugin generated 3 characters of
>   unexpected output during activation.
>   If you notice “headers already sent”
>   messages, problems with syndication
>   feeds or other issues, try
>   deactivating or removing this plugin.

Without checking, it solved the problem or not I deactivated the plugin, thought it can break the site.

Is there any other solution to solved this problem?

**WordPress Version is 3.0.1**

Comment: *@metal-gear-solid:* You are asking lots of question here so I thought I'd ask you to please start paying attention to capitalization. Your title for this question is hard to understand because it starts with lowercase; I rewrote this *"didn't becomes didn''''''''''''''''''t in Wordpress WYSIWYG editor, How to solve this issue?"* so it will be easier to understand and not look like an error. Your lowercase "i"s make it hard to read your question. And WordPress is cased *"WordPress"* not *"Wordpress."*

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - Thanks for editing my question. I will take care with capitalization if future questions. I'm not a native english so my english and wrting skiils are bad. I'm learning.

Comment: *@metal-gear-solid:* Thanks for trying. I expected you might be a non-native speaker so I complete understand; your English is better than my French, for example. :) But that's why I asked for simple things like capitalization; that little bit should be easy for a non-English speaker but go a long way to make a question more readable.

Comment: *@MikeSchinkel:* Vraiment?

Answer (score 1):

The solution at that page is fine. The reason it's generating unexpected output is because you might have accidentally grabbed trailing whitespace when pasting it. If you use this instead:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: TurnOffSmartQuotes
Plugin URI:
Description: Stops WordPress from converting your quote symbols into smartquotes. The three lines below stop the smartquote conversion in 1) your post content, 2) your comments, and 3) your post excerpts.
Version: 0.1
Author: Katja Stokley
Author URI:
*/
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('comment_text', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wptexturize');
```

that should do the trick.

I'm not sure why WordPress isn't correctly texturizing "didn't", but that will fix the problem.

Comment: But in your code where you are closing the php tag? is it typo?

Comment: I just tried again. not i got plugin activated without error. but problem still not solved. if i write `didn't` it showing `didn''t`.I check in source it's this `<p>didn''t</p>`

Comment: You don't need to close php tags in files that are included but not run directly. I intentionally left the closing tag out because that's the best way to make sure there's no trailing whitespace being sent to the browser before it's ready.

Comment: I aslo tried this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hungred-smart-quotes/ but no effect

Comment: If you have any plugins running, deactivate them all, and switch the theme back to twentyten. If that fixes the problem, start re-activating them one by one (starting with the theme), checking if the problem returns between each one. This will allow you to isolate the problem.

Comment: Could it be something in the MySQL that is causing the replication of quotes to appear?

Comment: Only if a plugin or theme you're using is changing the MySQL, or running redundant quoting calls. Did you try my last advice of deactivating everything?